# Graph editor shows too high of values

Tags: graph-editor

I can't seem to find the menu item that adjust the coordinate value and it's going all the way up to 60 causing my curves to look flat.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO2nV.png]

I don't need it that high but when I zoom in, I zoom in on the frames too and it'll only show 20 frames when I get it to "mountain" curve.

I want it look like the below.  It captures over 160 frames and the value goes up to 10.  How do I adjust?

[image]

Thanks.

UPDATE:  I was able to set it back to normal by hovering over the graph editor and pressing "home".  However, I'm still not satisfied with this answer because it's so automated.  Isn't there a way I can freely adjust the Graph Y Axis?

Answer (score 1):

Hold down CTRL+MMB and move the mouse up or down in the window.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the little circle at the end of the scrollbar scroll region (top and bottom of the far right of your second image). This lets you change the scale of the visible region and so zoom in and out in each axis.

Comment: This actually worked for me! Should be accepted answer